# Flow: Throws error Cannot resolve module "react-redux" even tho it's installed

Tags: javascript, react-redux, flowtype

Even tho module is installed and it exists, Flow cannot resolve it and throws error.
See below:
1) Inside bash I ran `flow` and it throws error that module is not found

```
user@pc:~/code/project$ flow
Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/functionalities/Growth/index.js:3:25

Cannot resolve module react-redux.

     1│ // @flow
     2│ import React from "react"
     3│ import { connect } from "react-redux"
     4│
     5│ type Props = {
     6│   children: Function



Found 1 error
```

2) Below command checks whether directory exists and it does

```
user@pc:~/code/project$ ls node_modules | grep react-redux
react-redux
```

I tried to remove and reinstall both `node_modules` directory and `yarn.lock` file.

Versions should be matching:

```
flow version
Flow, a static type checker for JavaScript, version 0.77.0
```

.flowconfig:

```
[version]
0.77.0
```

[image]

This is very likely bug with Flow, I also submitted issue.

Comment: Meanwhile if someone else comes upon similar issue use `// $FlowFixMe` above import to ignore error.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

### How to fix it

You have two options:

1. stub the dependency by hand
2. bring in `flow-typed` to find the dependency type
   file/stub it for you

I use option 2 but it is nice to know what is happening underneath

#### Option 1

In `.flowconfig`, add a directory under `[libs]`,

```
...
[libs]
/type-def-libs
...
```

Now, create that directory at your project root and a file `/type-def-libs/react-redux` which contains,

```
declare module 'react-redux' {
  declare module.exports: any;
}
```

#### Option 2

- install `flow-typed`, if using yarn `yarn add -D flow-typed`

  - I prefer to install every locally to the project when possible
- run `yarn flow-typed install`

  - this will install any type definition files for modules that it finds AND it will stub any modules it doesn't find, which is similar to what we did in option 1

### Why is this error happening

Flow is looking for the **type** definition for the module you are importing. So while the module does exist in `/node_modules` that module doesn't have a type definition file checked into its code.

Comment: Thank you. Is it due to a recent change? This looks like Typescript (forced to type everything) .

Comment: @MacKentoch The type syntax between Flow and Typescript is very similar. Is this a recent change [to flow]? This is not new in Flow (using over the past 1yr+ as memory serves) you have needed to stub un-typed imports since the beginning of my use.

Comment: Have you been able to make the option 2 with flow-typed work in Intellij/Webstorm?

Comment: Option 2 worked perfectly for me on webStorm.. thanks

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue as you.

[image]

I resolved it by using [`flow-typed`](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed)

I did the following:

1. Install `flow-typed` globally. example: `$ npm install -g flow-typed`
2. Then inside your project root folder, run `$ flow-typed install react-redux@5.0.x` 
   [image]

   `• Searching for 1 libdefs...
   • flow-typed cache not found, fetching from GitHub...
   • Installing 1 libDefs...
   • react-redux_v5.x.x.js
   └> ./flow-typed/npm/react-redux_v5.x.x.js
   react-redux`

   You should see this if the install was successful.
3. Then try running flow again `$ npm run flow` in your project. The error with `react-redux` will no longer be there.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot.  I adapted the solution a bit though, here is what I came up with: 
1. install `flow-typed` locally. `npm i -D flow-typed`
2. within `package.json` scripts section add `'flow-typed: flow-typed`,
3. from the root of your project run `npm run flow-typed create-stub <lib>`

Answer (score 5):

### Alternative solution (for some cases)

Check your `.flowconfig` and remove `<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/.*` under the field `[ignore]` (in case you have it there).

**UPDATE 1** (by [arka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11922447/arka)):
Or you can add `!<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/react-redux/.*` after `<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/.*`. This will ignore all the modules except for `react-redux`.

---

Thanks to @meloseven who solved it [here](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6646#issuecomment-447272772).

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, it only works for certain cases. See discussion here for more info about when it helped: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6646#issuecomment-447272772

Answer (score 0):

I checked my `package.json` file and noticed `react-redux` was missing. I manually added it to the dependencies `"react-redux": "x.x.x"` and ran `npm install`  thereafter. Note that the version number should be compatible with the other modules.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you provide the path under 'ignore' in .flowconfig, like this:

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/.*
```

and not like this:

```
.*/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components
.*/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core
....
```